# How to remove all lines that have one value in the line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I have a file as the following

```
input file
0.0  4  6  5  1  2  9  4  5  1  ..... 
0.25
0.5  3  1  
1.0  3  7  8  2  
1.5  3  3  3  4  6  4  5   
2.0  
2.5  6  7  6  9
```

I want to delete all lines that have only one value in the line so the result will be like this

```
out file  
0.0  4  6  5  1  2  9  4  5  1  ..... 
0.5  3  1  
1.0  3  7  8  2  
1.5  3  3  3  4  6  4  5   
2.5  6  7  6  9
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach using `awk`.  Uses NF (number of fields) to only print the lines where number of fields is greater than 1.

```
awk <oldfile >newfile 'NF>1'
```

Example

```
awk <oldfile >newfile 'NF>1'
cat newfile
0.0  4  6  5  1  2  9  4  5  1  .....
0.5  3  1
1.0  3  7  8  2
1.5  3  3  3  4  6  4  5
2.5  6  7  6  9
```

Comment: will them redirections in between of the arguments work? shouldn't they be after the query?

Comment: Yes, see example I've now added.  Redirections can be before or after.  `awk 'NF>1' <oldfile >newfile` works equally well, as does `awk 'NF>1' oldfile >newfile`

Answer (score 4):

For there to be two or more numbers then there must be at least one separator.  If this is a `space` then the grep would simply be

```
grep ' '
```

If you file may have extraneous spaces at the end of the line then search for a space followed by a digit or `.` (in case a number may be `.25`).

```
grep ' [0-9.]'
```

If you may have extraneous spaces at the beginning *or* end and extra spaces in the middle then

```
grep '[0-9.]  *[0-9].'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with grep or sed.

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:].]\+[[:space:]]*$/d' input >output
```

With grep, use the `-E` option for regular expressions, and `-v` option to exclude matches:

```
grep -v -E '^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:].]+[[:space:]]*$' input >output
```

The reason for the pattern is to ignore lines which do not have a *numeric* value, and to handle cases with leading or trailing blanks.  If none of that is of interest, a simpler solution "works".